# Naming convention for the primary key in a Table

Tags: cakephp

I am learning the Model relationship types in cakephp.
I have built two tables and in one of the Table A, 
I got these fields in it:

```
Table A {postID, topic, content} 
Table B {replyID, content, postID}
```

And when I ran the web page, a bunch of error related to SQL
 popped up saying that
cakephp couldn't find post_id.

It is weird that I have already declared 
the $primaryKey to be using postID in the tableA.php under Models folder, 
but cakephp seemed want me to change the ID field to post_id instead of postID,
because the error disappeared after I have changed the primaryKey to post_id.

ANy ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cake expects your fields to be lower case, with words separated by underscores.  See the CakePHP [Model and Database Naming Conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/24/Model-and-Database-Conventions) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

By convention the field with the primary key is named `id`.